# Is there such a notion as mean residual lifetime at the time of failure?

Tags: mean, expected-value, conditional-expectation

The mean residual lifetime (MRL) is a well understood notion: If $X \sim f(\cdot), F(\cdot)$, then, the MRL at any time $t$ is: $m(t) = E[X-t | X > t]$.

Are there well understood properties of $E[m(X)]$?

Comment: What do you really want? I suspect that expected residual lifetime at the time of death is zero? (Leaving aside metaphysical questions about an afterlife).

Comment: That's not true. If $X \sim Exp(1)$, then, $m(t) = 1$, so, $E[m(X)] = 1$.

One way to think about MRL at the time of failure is as follows: Conditional on the time of failure, just moments before failure, what is the MRL? Now, take an expectation over the time of failure. It's definitely not 0.